# PHP: create new methods on a referenced object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter framework. What i'm trying to achieve, is to make two setter/getter methods available on the super class that Codeigniter uses: the CI_Controller.

I've created a "hook"(something like middleware) that will run each time, after the controller constructor is executed:

```
class Response {
  public function init()
  {
      // load the instance
      $this->CI =& get_instance();

      $this->CI->response=array(
        'content'=> null,
        'status' => 'ok',
        'errorMessage' => null
    );

  }
}
```

This code will just set a property "response" on the object. I would like to create also a getter and a setter, but don't know how.

I've tried stuff like:

```
$this->CI->setResponse = function($arr){
          foreach($arr as $key => $value){
              $this->data[$key] = $value;
          }
       }
```

Of course it doesn't work.

How can it be done?

Comment: You should extend the `CI_Controller` class per the [`docs`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html) rather than trying to inject code like this because it will be heinously unmaintainable.

Comment: this seems like a lot of work for what amounts to setting a response which can be done with a simple model... as for your question, why can't you just create get and set methods in the library `Response` you've created. anything is globally available in CI as long as it is loaded via autoload or MY_Controller and can be accessed via `$this->response->get()` `$this->response->set()` as long as response is a library or model.

Comment: MonkeyZeus: Thanks..i had a feeling that i'm not even using the correct Codeigniter functionality. Alex: what do u mean by a simple model? How would u do it?

Comment: Since release of **PHP 5.0** (I think, that's 2004 .. how old are your tutorials?!), objects should not be passed by reference.

Comment: I'd have to know the purpose...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my `Response_model` autoload it via `autoload.php` and save it in models.

```
class Response_model extends CI_Model {

    private $response = array();

    /**
     * Adds parameters to output
     * 
     * @param mixed $ka String key or array
     * @param type $value Value if using string
     * @return $this
     */
    public function add($ka, $value = null) {
        if (is_string($ka)) {
            $this->response = array_merge($this->response, array($ka => $value));
        } elseif (is_array($ka)) {
            $this->response = array_merge($this->response, $ka);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Status: success
     * 
     * @param type $msg
     * @return $this
     */
    public function success($msg = null) {

        $this->response = array('status' => 'success', 'msg' => $msg);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Status: error
     * 
     * @param type $msg
     * @return $this
     */
    public function error($msg = null) {

        $this->response = array('status' => 'error', 'msg' => $msg);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets form_validation errors
     * 
     * @return $this
     */
    public function form_errors() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $errors = array();
        foreach ($this->form_validation->error_array() as $field_name => $error) {
            $errors[] = array('id' => $field_name, 'msg' => $error);
        }
        $this->response = array('status' => 'error', 'form_errors' => $errors);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Straight output, no status or msg
     * 
     * @param mixed $output
     * @return $this
     */
    public function output($output) {
        $this->response = $output;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Renders JSON response
     * e.g. {"status":"error","msg":"some_error","some_value":"some_key"}
     * with the appropriate headers
     * 
     * @param boolean $exit TRUE (default) exits()
     * @param string|array $json_params e.g. array(JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, JSON_HEX_TAG)
     * @return void
     */
    public function json($exit = true, $json_params = null) {
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        if (is_null($json_params)) {
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode($this->response));
        } else {
            if (is_array($json_params)) {
                $params = implode(' | ', $json_params);
            } else {
                $params = $json_params;
            }
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode($this->response, $params));
        }
        $this->output->_display();
        if ($exit) {
            exit;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Renders javascript output
     * 
     * @param boolean $exit TRUE (default) exits()
     */
    public function js($exit = true) {
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/javascript');
        $this->output->set_output($this->response);
        $this->output->_display();
        if ($exit) {
            exit;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Renders HTML response
     * 
     * @param boolean $exit TRUE (default) exits()
     * @return void
     */
    public function html($exit = true) {
        $this->output->set_content_type('html');
        $this->output->set_output($this->response);
        $this->output->_display();
        if ($exit) {
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

Usage when you want to set a json response:

```
$this->response->success('Some message')->add(array('somevar' => $somevar))->json();
```

As long as it is autoloaded (or loaded in a `MY_Controller` in `application/core` and the subsequent controllers extend `MY_Controller`) `$this->response` is globally available like any other model or library that you load globally.